# How to create animated background gradient like Instagram app?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio, android-animation

Below are screenshots of instagram app. The background keeps on transforming from one gradient to other very beautifully. 
[image: Instagram background gradient]

[image: Instagram background gradient]

I want to know how can I achieve this. IS THERE ANY CODE TO ANIMATE A GRADIENT AUTOMATICALLY OR DO I NEED TO ADD DIFFERENT GRADIENTS WITH SLIGHT VARIATION, and if  I use it won't cause any copyright issues with Instagram? I have tried animating using multiple gradient files with slight variation using Frame Animation but it isn't smooth and doesn't work well. Thanks

Comment: you can follow my gist for that https://gist.github.com/deepak786/12eee8412fa7914a16774ce546e1a089

Comment: @DeepakGoyal what should i do if i want to continue this color change animation in second activity too.. just like Instagram if we switch to login to sign in color changing animation is continued !!

Comment: @RuchaBhatt you need to apply this animation in the second activity too. But if want to continue the same animation to another activity, you can try with fragments and provide the animation to fragment activity. By this, if you change the fragment your animation still continues.

Comment: @DeepakGoyal but what if i want to continue this animation and i'm using activities all ready i cant switch to fragments any other solution? thank you for reply. :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Create a TransitionDrawable to change between two drawables that you use for the background.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<transition xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- use whatever drawables you want, gradients, shapes etc-->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/start" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/end" />
</transition>
```

[Transition Drawables in Android](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/TransitionDrawable.html)

```
TransitionDrawable trans = (TransitionDrawable) myLayout.getBackground();
trans.startTransition(2000);
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: but how to repeat it ? because it end with a blink effect .

Comment: `java.lang.ClassCastException: android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.TransitionDrawable`

Comment: maybe this will help: [link](http://www.viralandroid.com/2017/04/animated-gradient-background-in-android.html)