# How to get gradient effect

Tags: android, android-studio, animation, gradient

Hello I want to know how I can get background effect like [this](https://youtu.be/nCpzKMc5Le0) ?
Even the colours are different with different contacts.

I have tried some tutorials.

1. [this](https://gist.github.com/deepak786/12eee8412fa7914a16774ce546e1a089)
2. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32224798/5521469)

and others.

But did not get exact effect. Please help. Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35439717/2949612

Comment: Or you can check [this](https://github.com/dynamitechetan/Flowing-Gradient) library.

Comment: draw the `GradientDrawable` (or `LinearGradient` if you need more features) using `ValueAnimator` / `ObjectAnimator`

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
        android:startColor="#3B5998"
        android:endColor="#00000000"
        android:angle="45"/>    
</shape>
```

and then in your main xml

```
 <include
        android:id="@+id/include1"
        layout="@layout/actionbar" />
```

Answer (score 0):

for example in XML

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
        android:startColor="#2E383E"
        android:endColor="#798B97"
        android:angle="45"/>    
</shape>
```

Create a TransitionDrawable to change between two drawables that you use for the background.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<transition xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- use whatever drawables you want, gradients, shapes etc-->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/start" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/end" />
</transition>
```

[Transition Drawables in Android](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/TransitionDrawable.html)

```
TransitionDrawable trans = (TransitionDrawable) myLayout.getBackground();
trans.startTransition(2000);
```